# Disable moving to Outlook in SSRS?

Tags: email, reporting-services, hyperlink

I have a SQL Server Reporting Services report where one of the columns has user ids in email address format. When I export this report to PDF format and click on the user id it moves to Outlook.

I have read about disabling hyperlinks and used both:

```
(=IIFGlobals!RenderFormat.Name, "www.google.com",Nothing) 
=IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive, "http://10.210.251.132/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx", Nothing)
```

But neither is working. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, you have a report that displays some email addresses and when the report is rendered as a PDF document the email addresses appear as clickable links. When a user clicks one of the email address in the PDF document, the link launches Microsoft Outlook (to create a new email message).

Unfortunately I think this is a feature of PDF documents, or at least the PDFs generated by Reporting Services. The email address seems to be automatically identified as such and a link created in the document - I can't see any way to control this from within the report code.

The only thing I can suggest is to insert a space into the address to stop the PDF renderer identifying it and creating a link, e.g.

my.email@address.com  >  my.email @ address.com

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I agree that its inbuilt feature in PDF.